# Mapbox - onNavigationFinished() method in android studio does not send me to another activity once finished

Tags: java, android, navigation, mapbox

Mapbox - I implemented the onNavigationFinished() method in android studio using the mapbox navigation UI

I am a beginner at coding so please help.

i found this at https://docs.mapbox.com/android/navigation/overview/user-interaction/

So basically i want it to send me to another activity, but it doesnt seem to call the onNavigationFinished method

```
@Override
public void onNavigationFinished() {
    SendUserToPostActivity();
}

private void SendUserToPostActivity() {
    Intent postIntent = new Intent(RouteActivity.this, PostActivity.class);
    postIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(postIntent);
    finish();
}
```

[image: mapbox screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By `implements NavigationListener` in your `activity` or `fragment`
sample code https://docs.mapbox.com/android/navigation/examples/navigationview-with-fragment/

Comment: I have another issue, once the navigation has finished I want to start another Activity, but it doesnt seem  to work.

Comment: Happy to help you :) Please post your question in StackOverflow